# How to determine if range (table columns) is not completely empty?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I need data validation to check if the selected range(table columns) are completely empty.

If completely empty MsgBox "error".

If at the same time not all the cells in the selected range contains values, program should move to the next process.

```
Sub test()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E3:F15")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Range is empty!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Range is not empty!"
    End If
End Sub
```

I found the above sample but it only checks if the range is completely empty or the range is not completely empty.

Comment: *check if the selected range(table columns) are completely empty (if completely empty MsgBox"error") and at the same time not all the cells in the selected range contains values* - what do you mean exactly? can you come up with a screenshot of an example?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Sub Test()
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("E3:F15")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Range is not empty!"
Else
    MsgBox "Range has some empty cells!"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to do a data validation to check if the selected range(table columns) are **completely empty**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("E3:F15") '<~~ Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet

    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = rng.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Range is completely empty!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Range is not completely empty!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the result from this condition different than the one that the OP already has 
- `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E3:F15")) = 0` ?

Comment: `CountA` takes "formulas" into consideration. Put `=IF(A1=B1,"","")` formula in cell `E3` of  `E3:F15`. My code will give you `0` and `CountA` will give you `1`

Comment: Yup, if the problem of the OP are the empty formulas, then it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply..

i was able to clarify the issue with the below code

```
Sub EmptyRange()
Dim i As Range
Dim bEmpty As Boolean
Empty = False
For Each iIn Range("G4:H14")
    If IsEmpty(i) = False Then
       Empty = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

If Empty = False Then
    MsgBox ""
Else
    MsgBox ""
End If
End Sub
```

hope this will help someone else as well.

Appreciate the support guys..
thanks